# two submits buttons ,but the first returns empty

Tags: javascript, html

i have the first select options

```
  <form id="infform" method="post">
      <select id="infmenu" name ="infmenu" size="1" class="select"  >
        <option value="0" >Please Select your article</option>
        <option value="3"  selected='selected' > value 1</option>
        <option value="2"  > value 2</option>
        <option value="18"  > value 3</option>
        <option value="16"  > value 4</option>
     </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddenselect" value="3" />
  </form>
```

and the second is

```
     <form action="" method="POST" id="form0">
        <input type="text" name="date0" class="tcal" value="" readonly="readonly" /><br />
        <input type="image"   src="../submit.png"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="submit0" />
     </form>
```

this my javascript

```
     function displayv() {
    var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text();
    $("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);

    $("select > option:first").prop("disabled", "disabled")
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function() {
        displayv();
    });
    displayv();

    $("select#infmenu").change(function() {
        $("#infform").submit();    
    });
});
```

now when i select the first option the page refresh and i get the value selected. 
and when i submit the second submit the page refreshes and the first select option returns empty `Please Select your article`.

so how should this be fixed please .

EDIT :
this the php how i handle between them.

```
 if (isset($_POST['infmenu'])){

  $infmenu = $_POST['infmenu']; 
     // some sql of updating here
    }

  if (isset($_POST['submit0'])){
     //some updating sql here
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear to me what your question really is.

If you're saying you're not seeing your select item value when you submit the second form, then that is normal and expected. You have two independent forms so when you submit the second form, the data from the first form will not be sent to the server.

The submit button /image only sends data for the inputs within it's own form, not data from any other forms within your html body tag.

Edited to add: you could:

- have a single form tag instead of two
- modify your jquery so that it puts the select value into the hidden field of the second form s well as the hidden field of the first. Then when second form is submitted, have your PHP script read the hidden field value and use that when rendering the HTML to decide which option has the selected attribute.
- use cookies with some JavaScript to set the cookie when the value of select changes
- use Ajax to do a partial submit - assuming server doesn't need to know value of select item when dealing with second form

Comment: yes its that what u said , so i just want keep the value selected from the first selection option ,

Comment: http is a stateless protocol so unless you use cookies or submit the second form using ajax, then that's not possible.

Comment: is there a way to dont make them independent ?

Comment: Put them inside the same form tag or use the PHP session cookie functions - its been years since I did PHP but a google search or Searching here should get you help on doing that

Comment: Updated my answer with some suggestions

Comment: can you share an exemple from my exemple to do the first and second of your solution options ? thx for your time

Comment: have done this but didnt work `document.getElementById("infmenu").select.value = "<?php echo $infmenu;  ?>"`

Comment: for the first option, just remove yor form tags from around the unoput tags in the second form and place those tags inside the first form. For the second, you need to find the select option that matches the hidden field's value and mark it with the "selected" attribute.

Comment: thx for reply Steve, the first i tried it and it worked, but i want you to show me the second option koz i didnt understand .cn you give exemple?

Comment: sorry i have read that form inside form is malformed html and i have met other problems that when i submit the first the second also will submit koz they are in same form . can you please explain for me your second options ?

Comment: yes you cant nest one form inside another, what I meant was only have ONE form tag with the two submit links (which is possible, you can have as many submit buttons/images inside one form as you like) Is there a special reason why you need it to be two separate form? The second option in your php code when you;re constructing your options on the select list, you need to add the "selected" attribute to it if that option is the same value as that contained in the hidden field. I'm not an expert on php so I cant give you code.

Comment: yes i have many forms so i cant make all in one :) , but ok i have solved it thx by session .

Answer (score 0):

There is no `action=""` assigned to the first button.

Comment: added action but its the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms.

When you click the submit in the second form, of course the data of the first form is not submitted.

Also, the submit button in the second form has no name, so you perhaps cannot evaluate in PHP if the button is clicked. But that's a different story

You should make the two forms one.

If they are too far apart on your page. You should save the value of the select box in the hidden field in the second form with php